# laravel 5.4 migration not working properly

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I got this issue when I use laravel migration to create a table in the database. I don't know what might be wrong with it as I use the same command on my previous system. This is the error I got while using composer to create the table.

> $ php artisan migrate Migration table created successfully.
>
> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1071 Specified key was t   oo long; max key
>   length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique 
>   `users_email_unique`(`email`))
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
>   1071 Specified key was t   oo long; max key length is 767 bytes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel 5.4 uses `utf8mb4` by default. One way to fix this error, is to default back to `utf8`.

Go to your `config\database.php` and change the database `charset` to `uft8` and the `collation` to `utf8_unicode_ci`:

```
'mysql' => [
    //..
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    //..
],
```

Answer (score 2):

The character limit depends on the character set you use. `Laravel` is using `utf8mb4` for which the character limit of the largest index is `191`.

You just need to set your character limit to correct one. Read this from 
[Laravel Index Length](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#indexes)

> Index Lengths & MySQL / MariaDB
>
> Laravel uses the `utf8mb4` character set by default, which includes
>   support for storing "emojis" in the database. If you are running a
>   version of `MySQL` older than the `5.7.7` release or `MariaDB` older than
>   the `10.2.2` release, you may need to manually configure the default
>   string length generated by migrations in order for MySQL to create
>   indexes for them. You may configure this by calling the
>   `Schema::defaultStringLength`method within your `AppServiceProvider`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

> Alternatively, you may enable the `innodb_large_prefix` option for your
>   database. Refer to your database's documentation for instructions on
>   how to properly enable this option.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug in Laravel 5.4

To fix it, place this above the Schema::create method call:

```
Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
```

Read more here:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/17508